# Count the number of times a WordPress shortcode is used in a post

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have the following WordPress shortcode function:

```
function wp_shortcode() {
 static $i=1;
 $return = '['.$i.']';
 $i++;
 return $return;
}
add_shortcode('shortcode', 'wp_shortcode');
```

This works fine. The `$i` variable gets incremented each time the function is called in the article. So for

```
[shortcode][shortcode][shortcode][shortcode]
```

the output is as expected

```
[1][2][3][4]
```

but

if the article has more than one page, than the counter resets on the next article page. So for:

```
[shortcode][shortcode][shortcode][shortcode]
<!--nextpage-->
[shortcode][shortcode][shortcode][shortcode]
```

the output is

```
[1][2][3][4]
<!--nextpage-->
[1][2][3][4]
```

instead of the wanted output of:

```
[1][2][3][4]
<!--nextpage-->
[5][6][7][8]
```

Anyway to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after researching a bit more @diggy's idea with pre processing the_content and adding the $atts to the shorcodes before the shortcodes are rendered, I came up with this:

```
function my_shortcode_content( $content ) {
 //check to see if the post has your shortcode, skip do nothing if not found
 if( has_shortcode( $content, 'shortcode' ) ):

  //replace any shortcodes to the basic form ([shortcode 1] back to [shortcode])
  //usefull when the post is edited and more shortcodes are added
  $content = preg_replace('/shortcode .]/', 'shortcode]', $content);

  //loop the content and replace the basic shortcodes with the incremented value
  $content = preg_replace_callback('/shortocode]/', 'rep_count', $content);

 endif;

return $content;
}
add_filter( 'content_save_pre' , 'my_shortcode_content' , 10, 1);

function rep_count($matches) {
 static $i = 1;
return 'shortcode ' . $i++ .']';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. A possible solution below, however not exactly elegant because it requires you to have a fixed number of shortcodes on each page, e.g. 4:

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'wp_shortcode' );
function wp_shortcode() {
    global $page;
    $spp = 4;
    static $i = 1;
    $ii = $i + ( ( $page - 1 ) * $spp );
    $return = '<a href="#f'.$ii.'" name="r'.$ii.'">['.$ii.']</a>';
    $i++;
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of shortcodes is different for each article/page

Comment: Would it be possible to initialize a static variable with another variable? So, if i add an attribute to the shortcode like this [shortcode 5], in the function can static $i = $atts[0] which basically is static i = 5? I tried but I get an error so maybe I have to adjust something.

Comment: PHP doc says: "Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed." Something like this could work, but only looks at and passes the attr of the first shortcode on the page: `if( ! defined( 'SH_C' ) ) define( 'SH_C', $atts[0] ); static $i = SH_C;` But if you start adding numbers as atts, incrementing programmatically stops making sense, no? Maybe a better idea to preprocess `the_content` and add atts dynamically, i.e. before the shortcodes are processed and rendered?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to just count the total tags in a page/post you can use this:

```
function count_shortcodes( $content, $tag ) {
    if ( false === strpos( $content, '[' ) ) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ( shortcode_exists( $tag ) ) {
        preg_match_all( '/' . get_shortcode_regex() . '/', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
        if ( empty( $matches ) )
            return 0;

        $count = 0;
        foreach ( $matches as $shortcode ) {
            if ( $tag === $shortcode[2] ) {
                $count++;
            } elseif ( ! empty( $shortcode[5] ) && has_shortcode( $shortcode[5], $tag ) ) {
                $count++;
            }
        }

        return $count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happens, because on every page load you redefined your function, so `static $i=1;` will executed always.

Maybe you want to use a `$_SESSION` variable. But do not forget the `session_start()` somewhere in `init` callback.

```
function wp_shortcode() {
    if (empty($_SESSION["myCounter"])) {
        $_SESSION["myCounter"] = 1;
    }
    $return = '<a href="#f' . $_SESSION["myCounter"] . '" name="r' 
        . $_SESSION["myCounter"] . '">[' 
        . $_SESSION["myCounter"] . ']</a>';
    $_SESSION["myCounter"]++;
    return $return;
}
add_shortcode('shortcode', 'wp_shortcode');
```

Setting the session, put it into the `functions.php`

```
add_action('init', 'my_init');
function my_init() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
    //Other init here
}
```

Comment: Well this works, as the counter keeps going up, but every refresh of the page make the counter increment so without a session end when the user leaves the article this won't work. The only way for this solution to work would be to have post specific sessions. So when you start reading an article the session starts and when you go to another article the session ends.