# Extract shortcode parameters in content - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Think about a post content like below:

```
[shortcode a="a_param"]
... Some content and shortcodes here
[shortcode b="b_param"]
.. Again some content here
[shortcode c="c_param"]
```

I have a shortcode that takes 3 or more parameters. 
I want to find out how many times the shortcode is used at the content and its parameters in an array like,

```
array (
[0] => array(a => a_param, b=> null, c=>null),
[1] => array(a => null, b=> b_param, c=>null),
[2] => array(a => null, b=> null, c=>c_param),
)
```

I need to do this in the_content filter, wp_head filter or something similar.

How can I do this ?

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress shortcode count number of times used in post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507320/wordpress-shortcode-count-number-of-times-used-in-post)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In wordpress [get_shortcode_regex()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) function returns regular expression used to search for shortcodes inside posts.

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
```

Then preg_match the pattern with the post content

```
if (   preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches ) )
```

If it return true, then extracted shortcode details are saved in $matches variable.

**Try**

```
global $post;
$result = array();
//get shortcode regex pattern wordpress function
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();


if (   preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches ) )
{
    $keys = array();
    $result = array();
    foreach( $matches[0] as $key => $value) {
        // $matches[3] return the shortcode attribute as string
        // replace space with '&' for parse_str() function
        $get = str_replace(" ", "&" , $matches[3][$key] );
        parse_str($get, $output);

        //get all shortcode attribute keys
        $keys = array_unique( array_merge(  $keys, array_keys($output)) );
        $result[] = $output;

    }
    //var_dump($result);
    if( $keys && $result ) {
        // Loop the result array and add the missing shortcode attribute key
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            // Loop the shortcode attribute key
            foreach ($keys as $attr_key) {
                $result[$key][$attr_key] = isset( $result[$key][$attr_key] ) ? $result[$key][$attr_key] : NULL;
            }
            //sort the array key
            ksort( $result[$key]);              
        }
    }

    //display the result
    print_r($result);


}
```

Comment: This won't work if there are any spaces in the attribute value because str_replace() affects them too.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Zähller Thank you pointing my mistake. I will correct it soon and will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just to save time, this is the function I made based on @Tamil Selvan C answer :

```
function get_shortcode_attributes( $shortcode_tag ) {
        global $post;
        if( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, $shortcode_tag ) ) {
            $output = array();
            //get shortcode regex pattern wordpress function
            $pattern = get_shortcode_regex( [ $shortcode_tag ] );
            if (   preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches ) )
            {
                $keys = array();
                $output = array();
                foreach( $matches[0] as $key => $value) {
                    // $matches[3] return the shortcode attribute as string
                    // replace space with '&' for parse_str() function
                    $get = str_replace(" ", "&" , trim( $matches[3][$key] ) );
                    $get = str_replace('"', '' , $get );
                    parse_str( $get, $sub_output );

                    //get all shortcode attribute keys
                    $keys = array_unique( array_merge(  $keys, array_keys( $sub_output )) );
                    $output[] = $sub_output;
                }
                if( $keys && $output ) {
                    // Loop the output array and add the missing shortcode attribute key
                    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
                        // Loop the shortcode attribute key
                        foreach ($keys as $attr_key) {
                            $output[$key][$attr_key] = isset( $output[$key] )  && isset( $output[$key] ) ? $output[$key][$attr_key] : NULL;
                        }
                        //sort the array key
                        ksort( $output[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $output;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```